# Properly round financial data

Tags: c#, winforms, math, financial

I decided to re-create my question:

```
decimal dTotal = 0m;
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in _totals)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value.ToString()))
        {
            dTotal += Convert.ToDecimal(item.Value);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(dTotal / 3600m);
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Round(dTotal / 3600m, 2));
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Divide(dTotal, 3600m));
```

The above code returns:

> 579.99722222222222222222222222
>
> 580.00
>
> 579.99722222222222222222222222

So, that is where my issues are coming from, I really need it to just display the `579.99`; but any round, be it `decimal.Round` or `Math.Round` still return `580`; even the string formats for `{0:F}` return `580.00`.

How can i properly do this?

Comment: Try dividing by 3600.0 and see if that works?

Comment: @simchona it woudln't work, that int gets promoted to double anyway

Comment: It might be a rounding error caused by the internal representation itself. Have you tried with decimal?

Comment: Hiya - these 2 links might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840793/rounding-standards-financial-calculations && http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008826/what-data-type-should-i-use-to-represent-money-in-c , cheers

Comment: don't use var, explicitly type things as Decimal

Comment: Where are you doing your math? What language?

Comment: @zackrspv: read this: http://floating-point-gui.de/ since doubles aren't always as precise as one would need, they invented the decimal datatype, which is more precise

Comment: @BlackBear: It's not the level of precision which is important here, it's the base used.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes, I didn't explain well

Answer (score 10):

**New answer (to new question)**

Okay, so you've got a value of `579.99722222222222222222222222` - and you're asking that to be rounded to two decimal places. Isn't 580.00 the natural answer? It's closer to the original value than 579.99 is. It sounds like you essentially want *flooring* behaviour, but with a given number of digits. For that, you can use:

```
var floored = Math.Floor(original * 100) / 100;
```

In this case, you can do both in one step:

```
var hours = Math.Floor(dTotal / 36) / 100;
```

... which is equivalent to

```
var hours = Math.Floor((dTotal / 3600) * 100) / 100;
```

**Original answer (to original question)**

Sounds like you've probably got `payTotal` in an inappropriate form to start with:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        decimal pay = 2087975.7m;
        decimal time = pay / 3600;
        Console.WriteLine(time); // Prints 579.99325
    }
}
```

This is the problem:

```
var payTotal = 2087975.7;
```

That's assigning `payTotal` to a `double` variable. The value you've actually got is 2087975.69999999995343387126922607421875, which isn't what you wanted. Any time you find yourself casting from `double` to `decimal` or vice versa, you should be worried: chances are you've used the wrong type somewhere. Currency values should *absolutely* be stored in `decimal` rather than `double` (and there are various other Stack Overflow questions talking about when to use which).

See my two articles on floating point for more info:

- [Binary floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx)
- [Decimal floating point in .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx)

(Once you've got correct results, formatting them is a different matter of course, but that shouldn't be too bad...)

Comment: @zackrspv: As I can see, the value is 2087990... and this is the first time you've even mentioned `dTotal`. I've given a short but complete program showing the calculation working. Can you give a similar one with it *not* working?

Comment: @zackrspv: *Completely* changing the question feels against the spirit of the site to me - it makes any existing answers look completely wrong. As it happens I'm around to change my answer, but in future I'd suggest editing the question to *include* the old one. (At least you have acknowledged that it's "recreated".)

Comment: @zackrspv: No, you should learn to come up with short but complete programs which demonstrate the same problem, but without using anything proprietary. In this case it's particularly easy to do. I've updated my answer, by the way.

Comment: @zackrspv: Have rolled back your edit - now that I've *answered* the edited question, you might as well leave it there... otherwise you've wasted my time *twice*.